# Got AttributeError when importing theano

Tags: python-3.x, theano

I got following error when importing theano by `import theano` in Python3.8. How do I fix it?
Last line is:

`AttributeError: module 'numpy.distutils.__config__' has no attribute 'blas_opt_info'`

> [~] python -c "import theano"
> 19:45:49 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line
> 168, in fetch_val_for_key
> return theano_cfg.get(section, option)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/configparser.py",
> line 781, in get
> d = self._unify_values(section, vars)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/configparser.py",
> line 1149, in _unify_values
> raise NoSectionError(section) from None configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'blas'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line
> 327, in **get**
> val_str = fetch_val_for_key(self.fullname,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line
> 172, in fetch_val_for_key
> raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'blas.ldflags'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/**init**.py", line 124,
> in 
> from theano.scan_module import (scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone,   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/scan_module/**init**.py",
> line 41, in 
> from theano.scan_module import scan_opt   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_opt.py",
> line 60, in 
> from theano import tensor, scalar   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/tensor/**init**.py",
> line 17, in 
> from theano.tensor import blas   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas.py", line
> 155, in 
> from theano.tensor.blas_headers import blas_header_text   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas_headers.py",
> line 987, in 
> if not config.blas.ldflags:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line
> 332, in **get**
> val_str = self.default()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py",
> line 1284, in default_blas_ldflags
> blas_info = np.distutils.**config**.blas_opt_info AttributeError: module 'numpy.distutils.**config**' has no attribute 'blas_opt_info'

PS: python3.8 macOS10.15

PSS: It is required by pymc3